# How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I don't understand how to use `$scope.$watch` and `$scope.$apply`. The official documentation isn't helpful.

What I don't understand specifically:

- Are they connected to the DOM?
- How can I update DOM changes to the model?
- What is the connection point between them?

I tried [this tutorial](http://css.dzone.com/articles/drag-and-drop-angularjs-using), but it takes the understanding of `$watch` and `$apply` for granted.

What do `$apply` and `$watch` do, and how do I use them appropriately?

Answer (score 1790, accepted):

You need to be aware about how AngularJS works in order to understand it.

### Digest cycle and $scope

First and foremost, AngularJS defines a concept of a so-called **digest cycle**. This cycle can be considered as a loop, during which AngularJS checks if there are any changes to all the variables **watched** by all the `$scope`s. So if you have `$scope.myVar` defined in your controller and this variable was **marked for being watched**, then you are implicitly telling AngularJS to monitor the changes on `myVar` in each iteration of the loop.

A natural follow-up question would be: Is everything attached to `$scope` being watched? Fortunately, no. If you would watch for changes to every object in your `$scope`, then quickly a digest loop would take ages to evaluate and you would quickly run into performance issues. That is why the AngularJS team gave us two ways of declaring some `$scope` variable as being watched (read below).

### $watch helps to listen for $scope changes

There are two ways of declaring a `$scope` variable as being watched.

1. By using it in your template via the expression `<span>{{myVar}}</span>`
2. By adding it manually via the `$watch` service

Ad 1)
This is the most common scenario and I'm sure you've seen it before, but you didn't know that this has created a watch in the background. Yes, it had! Using AngularJS directives (such as `ng-repeat`) can also create implicit watches.

Ad 2)
This is how you create your own **watches**. `$watch` service helps you to run some code when some value attached to the `$scope` has changed. It is rarely used, but sometimes is helpful. For instance, if you want to run some code each time 'myVar' changes, you could do the following:

```
function MyController($scope) {

    $scope.myVar = 1;

    $scope.$watch('myVar', function() {
        alert('hey, myVar has changed!');
    });

    $scope.buttonClicked = function() {
        $scope.myVar = 2; // This will trigger $watch expression to kick in
    };
}
```

### $apply enables to integrate changes with the digest cycle

You can think of the **`$apply` function as of an integration mechanism**. You see, each time you change some **watched variable attached to the `$scope`** object directly, AngularJS will know that the change has happened. This is because AngularJS already knew to monitor those changes. So if it happens in code managed by the framework, the digest cycle will carry on.

However, sometimes you want to **change some value outside of the AngularJS world** and see the changes propagate normally.
Consider this - you have a `$scope.myVar` value which will be modified within a jQuery's `$.ajax()` handler. This will happen at some point in future. AngularJS can't wait for this to happen, since it hasn't been instructed to wait on jQuery.

To tackle this, `$apply` has been introduced. It lets you start the digestion cycle explicitly. However, you should only use this to migrate some data to AngularJS (integration with other frameworks), but never use this method combined with regular AngularJS code, as AngularJS will throw an error then.

### How is all of this related to the DOM?

Well, you should really follow the tutorial again, now that you know all this. The digest cycle will make sure that the UI and the JavaScript code stay synchronised, by evaluating every watcher attached to all `$scope`s as long as nothing changes. If no more changes happen in the digest loop, then it's considered to be finished.

You can attach objects to the `$scope` object either explicitly in the Controller, or by declaring them in `{{expression}}` form directly in the view.

Further readings:

- *[Make Your Own AngularJS, Part 1: Scopes And Digest](http://teropa.info/blog/2013/11/03/make-your-own-angular-part-1-scopes-and-digest.html)*

Comment: what about using this? ("Control as" method)

Comment: Using "Control as" should have no impact on the information above. Using this.myVar puts myVar on the scope.

Comment: @ŁukaszBachman - "then you are explicitly telling Angular to monitor the changes". I think its 'implicitly' not 'explicitly'

Answer (score 164):

In AngularJS, we update our models, and our views/templates update the DOM "automatically" (via built-in or custom directives).

$apply and $watch, both being Scope methods, are not related to the DOM.

The [Concepts](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) page (section "Runtime") has a pretty good explanation of the $digest loop, $apply, the $evalAsync queue and the $watch list. Here's the picture that accompanies the text:

[image: $digest loop]

Whatever code has access to a scope – normally controllers and directives (their link functions and/or their controllers) – can set up a "[watchExpression](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$watch)" that AngularJS will evaluate against that scope. This evaluation happens whenever AngularJS enters its $digest loop (in particular, the "$watch list" loop). You can watch individual scope properties, you can define a function to watch two properties together, you can watch the length of an array, etc.

When things happen "inside AngularJS" – e.g., you type into a textbox that has AngularJS two-way databinding enabled (i.e., uses ng-model), an $http callback fires, etc. – $apply has already been called, so we're inside the "AngularJS" rectangle in the figure above. All watchExpressions will be evaluated (possibly more than once – until no further changes are detected).

When things happen "outside AngularJS" – e.g., you used bind() in a directive and then that event fires, resulting in your callback being called, or some jQuery registered callback fires – we're still in the "Native" rectangle. If the callback code modifies anything that any $watch is watching, call $apply to get into the AngularJS rectangle, causing the $digest loop to run, and hence AngularJS will notice the change and do its magic.

Comment: I understand the idea, what I don't understand is how the data actually gets transferred. I have a model which Is an object with lots of data, I use some of it to manipulate the DOM. then some of it gets changed. How do I put the changed data in the right place in the model? In the example I used he makes the manipulation and in the end simply uses `scope.$apply(scope.model)`, I don't understand what data gets transferred and how is it transferred to the right place in the model?

Comment: There is no magical data transfer taking place.  Normally with Angular apps, you should change the Angular models, which then drive view/DOM updates.  If you update the DOM outside of Angular, you'll have to manually update the models.  `scope.$apply(scope.model)` will simply evaluate `scope.model` as an Angular expression, and then enter a $digest loop.  In the article you reference, probably `scope.$apply()` would be sufficient, since the model is already being $watch'ed.  The stop() function is updating the model (I believe toUpdate is a reference to scope.model), and then $apply is called.

Comment: Looks like the AngularJS docs have shifted out from under this answer (the first link doesn't have "runtime" or `$watch` on the page, and the second link is broken -- as of now, anyhow). Painfully, [the archive versions](https://web.archive.org/web/20130126045037/http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope) didn't cache whatever async process created the content.

Answer (score 58):

AngularJS extends this *events-loop*, creating something called `AngularJS context`.

**$watch()**

Every time you bind something in the UI you insert a *`$watch` in a `$watch` list*.

```
User: <input type="text" ng-model="user" />
Password: <input type="password" ng-model="pass" />
```

Here we have `$scope.user`, which is bound to the first input, and we have `$scope.pass`, which is bound to the second one. Doing this we add two *`$watch`es to the `$watch` list*.

When our *template* is loaded, AKA in the linking phase, the compiler will look for every directive and creates all the `$watch`es that are needed.

AngularJS provides `$watch`, `$watchcollection` and `$watch(true)`. Below is a neat diagram explaining all the three taken from [watchers in depth](http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html).

[image]

```
angular.module('MY_APP', []).controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl)
function MyCtrl($scope,$timeout) {
  $scope.users = [{"name": "vinoth"},{"name":"yusuf"},{"name":"rajini"}];

  $scope.$watch("users", function() {
    console.log("**** reference checkers $watch ****")
  });

  $scope.$watchCollection("users", function() {
    console.log("**** Collection  checkers $watchCollection ****")
  });

  $scope.$watch("users", function() {
    console.log("**** equality checkers with $watch(true) ****")
  }, true);

  $timeout(function(){
     console.log("Triggers All ")
     $scope.users = [];
     $scope.$digest();

     console.log("Triggers $watchCollection and $watch(true)")
     $scope.users.push({ name: 'Thalaivar'});
     $scope.$digest();

     console.log("Triggers $watch(true)")
     $scope.users[0].name = 'Superstar';
     $scope.$digest();
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2Lyn0Lkb/

#### `$digest` loop

When the browser receives an event that can be managed by the AngularJS context the `$digest` loop will be fired. This loop is made from two smaller loops. One processes the `$evalAsync` queue, and the other one processes the `$watch list`. The `$digest` will loop through the list of `$watch` that we have

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function() {
  $scope.name = "vinoth";

  $scope.changeFoo = function() {
      $scope.name = "Thalaivar";
  }
});

{{ name }}
<button ng-click="changeFoo()">Change the name</button>
```

Here we have only one `$watch` because ng-click doesn’t create any watches.

We press the button.

1. The browser receives an event which will enter the AngularJS context
2. The `$digest` loop will run and will ask every $watch for changes.
3. Since the `$watch` which was watching for changes in $scope.name
   reports a change, it will force another `$digest` loop.
4. The new loop reports nothing.
5. The browser gets the control back and it will update the DOM
   reflecting the new value of $scope.name
6. The important thing here is that EVERY event that enters the AngularJS context will run a `$digest` loop. That means that every time we write a letter in an input, the loop will run checking every `$watch` in this page.

#### $apply()

If you call `$apply` when an event is fired, it will go through the angular-context, but if you don’t call it, it will run outside it. It is as easy as that. *`$apply` will call the `$digest()`* loop internally and it will iterate over all the watches to ensure the DOM is updated with the newly updated value.

The `$apply()` method will trigger watchers on the entire `$scope` chain whereas the `$digest()` method will only trigger watchers on the current `$scope` and its `children`. *When none of the higher-up `$scope` objects need to know about the local changes, you can use `$digest()`.*

Answer (score 19):

I found very in-depth videos which cover `$watch`, `$apply`, `$digest` and digest cycles in:

- *[AngularJS - Understanding Watcher, $watch, $watchGroup, $watchCollection, ng-change](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VS6vDlsqW7o&list=PLvZkOAgBYrsS_ugyamsNpCgLSmtIXZGiz&index=14)*
- *[AngularJS - Understanding digest cycle (digest phase or digest process or digest loop)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYuc1oSjhgY&list=PLvZkOAgBYrsS_ugyamsNpCgLSmtIXZGiz&index=15)*
- *[AngularJS Tutorial - Understanding $apply and $digest (in depth)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3m41zdbWboE&list=PLvZkOAgBYrsS_ugyamsNpCgLSmtIXZGiz&index=16)*

Following are a couple of slides used in those videos to explain the concepts (just in case, if the above links are removed/not working).

[image]

In the above image, "$scope.c" is not being watched as it is not used in any of the data bindings (in markup). The other two (`$scope.a` and `$scope.b`) will be watched.

[image]

From the above image: Based on the respective browser event, AngularJS captures the event, performs digest cycle (goes through all the watches for changes), execute watch functions and update the DOM. If not browser events, the digest cycle can be manually triggered using `$apply` or `$digest`.

More about `$apply` and `$digest`:

[image]

Answer (score 18):

There are `$watchGroup` and `$watchCollection` as well. Specifically, `$watchGroup` is really helpful if you want to call a function to update an object which has multiple properties in a view that is not dom object, for e.g. another view in canvas, **WebGL** or server request.

Here, the documentation [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

Comment: I would have commented about the `$watchCollection` but I see you already did.  [Here is documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) about it from the AngularJS site.  They provide a very nice visual of the `$watch` depth.  Note the information is close to the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 17):

Just finish reading ALL the above, boring and sleepy (sorry but is true). Very technical, in-depth, detailed, and dry.
Why am I writing? Because AngularJS is massive, lots of inter-connected concepts can turn anyone going nuts. I often asked myself, am I not smart enough to understand them? No! It's because so few can explain the tech in a **for-dummie language** w/o all the terminologies!
Okay, let me try:

**1) They are all event-driven things.** (I hear the laugh, but read on)

If you don't know what event-driven is Then
think you place a button
on the page, hook it up w/ a function using "on-click",  waiting for
users to click on it to trigger the actions you plant inside the
function.    Or think of "trigger" of SQL Server / Oracle.

**2) $watch is "on-click".**

What's special about is it takes 2 functions as parameters, first one
gives the value from the event, second one takes the value into
consideration...

**3) $digest is the boss who checks around tirelessly**,
bla-bla-bla but a good boss.

**4) $apply gives you the way when you want to do it manually**, like a fail-proof (in case on-click doesn't kick in, you force it to run.)

> **Now, let's make it visual. Picture this to make it even more easy to
> grab the idea:**

**In a restaurant,**

**- WAITERS**

are supposed to take orders from customers, this is

```
$watch(
  function(){return orders;},
  function(){Kitchen make it;}
);
```

**- MANAGER** running around to make sure all waiters are awake, responsive to any sign of changes from customers. This is `$digest()`

**- OWNER** has the ultimate power to drive everyone upon request, this is `$apply()`

Comment: This can be understood by a 5-year old. I appreciate this kind of answer. +1

Comment: "_I often asked myself, am I not smart enough to understand them? No!_" Apologies. I laughed.