# AngularJS - refresh view after http request, $rootScope.apply returns $digest already in progress

Tags: http, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I am simply trying to load data when my app starts. However, the view loads faster than the http request(of course). I want to refresh my view once my data has been properly loaded because that data defines my view.

I've tried $rootScope.apply from inside the factory where I do my http request, and I also tried directly doing the http request in my controller again with $scope.apply, and neither one worked as they both gave me **"$digest already in progress"**

Any idea how can I set up my code to make my views refresh on data load? I will be having several different http requests and I would like to know how to set them up properly! I would really appreciate any input!

Here is some of the code I am working with.

```
app.factory('HttpRequestFactory', function($http, $q) {
  var HttpRequestFactory = {
    async: function(url, params) {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      $http({
        url: url,
        method: post,
        params: params
      })
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          deferred.reject("An error occurred");
        });
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
  return HttpRequestFactory;
});
```

Factory

```
function initializeAll(){   
    HttpRequestFactory.async('../api', {action: 'getall'}).then(function(data) {
            //$rootScope.$apply(function () {
                allData = data;
            //});
        angular.forEach(allData, function(value, index){
            console.log('Voala!');
        });
    });
}
```

Controller calling the factory's function initializeAll()

```
app.controller("MainController", ["$scope", "$rootScope","MyFactory", 
    function($scope, $rootScope, MyFactory){
        MyFactory.initializeAll();
    
    }
]);
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle? I really doubt whether your code is working or not. At least I can see some syntax error. `method: post,` will break your code since the `post` needs to be a string. thanks.

Comment: hey sza, post is actually a constant that is declared in file and that is how it is working. I will try to get a jsFiddle.

Comment: Have you tried not to call `$apply`? The `success` callback of `$http` service is wrapped in a call to `$apply` by Angular itself.

Comment: Yeah I tried without it. The problem is that I have to click on something to register some action to refresh my view and then all the data appears again.

Comment: I would look into using a resolve on the route. As usual, John Lindquist has an excellent video on the topic: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P6KITGRQujQ

Answer (score 3):

Oh my !

You got the f**** matter with AngularJS !

In fact you have to do a "safeApply" like that for example :

```
$rootScope.safeApply = function(fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
        if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
            fn();
        }
    } else {
        this.$apply(fn);
    }
};
```

In AngularJS you can only have one $apply or $digest loop at the same time.

For details on these loops look at the docs : 
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts

It will explain what is the $apply loop and you'll understand a lot of things about the two-way-data-binding in AngularJS

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use `$apply`: use `$watch`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)

Calling `$apply` is (almost) always the wrong thing to do.  The only time you should ever be calling it is if you've triggered a change outside of an 'angular' method; here, since the trigger occurs in an angular `$http` request, you can't call `$apply` because it's already being done at that moment by the `$http` block.  Instead, what you want to do is `$watch`.

[Official Doc for $scope.$watch() here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#methods_$watch)

This will let you watch an object and update whenever it changes.  I assume that your view is based on `allData` and you want it to update immediately; if you're using an `ng` method, then the watch is automatically setup for you and no more work should be needed.  If you're using `allData` yourself inside a controller, you can write the watch in that controller like this:

```
$scope.$watch(function thingYouWantToWatch(){
         return <accessor call to allData here>;
      }, 
      function whatToDoOnChange(newValue, oldValue){
          $scope.myCoolThing = newValue; //this is the newValue of allData, or whatever you're watching.
      }
);
```

Comment: The official doc seems to have moved. Is this the equivalent now? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch