# Forcing a digest in Angular

Tags: angularjs

At some point after a user action I would like to cause a digest to occur, so the UI reflects a change in the data-model backing it.

I have a service that performs some change in a callback (asynchronously).

I understand that `$scope` only makes sense in the context of a controller. Can I achieve the same effect by performing `$apply()` on the `$rootScope`?

I have seen code that checks for `$$phase` or similar related to avoiding digest errors, what checks should I perform in order to trigger a digest safely?

Comment: `$rootScope.$apply()` should do the job just fine

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See this answer: [Running $apply on $rootScope vs any other scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868889/running-apply-on-rootscope-vs-any-other-scope)

You can call `$rootScope.$apply()` outside of a controller (i.e. in a service) in order to trigger a digest loop.

Alternatively, you could consider using `$broadcast` and `$on` to send a notification to other parts of your app when something needs refreshing. (See [Understanding Angular’s $scope and $rootScope event system $emit, $broadcast and $on](http://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/))

```
// in a service
$rootScope.$broadcast('myCustomEvent', {
  someProp: 'foobar'
  // other data
});

// in a controller or another service
$scope.$on('myCustomEvent', function (event, data) {
  console.log(data);
  // do something with this event
});
```

Comment: Do I need to guard against calling `apply()` during an existing digest?

Comment: See some of the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18626099/3191599
As I understand, there's rarely a need to call `$apply()` outside of working with non-Angular JS components. A broadcast/on or even a (light) `watch` should do the trick in most cases. Another reference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20847904/3191599