# Forcing digest in Angular with $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rendering, render

What's the best way to force a digest in Angular when using events outside of Angular itself - for example when loading an image in a jqLite container, I find myself doing this:

```
$img.on('load', function () {
    $timeout(function () { // Force digest
        $scope.isLoaded = true;
    });
});
```

This is a pattern I find myself using a lot. However it feels very dirty (like a hack-dirty, ugh). However, using [`$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) might trigger a [**"digest already in progress"** error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729122/angularjs-prevent-error-digest-already-in-progress-when-calling-scope-apply). I know I could [check for `$scope.$$phase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28288184/799327), but that feels equally dirty.

So, what's the **correct** way to get your changes to the DOM as fast as possible?

Comment: *"I find myself using a lot"*. Ideally you shouldn't need to use it often, so maybe you app design could be improved in the first place.

Comment: @dfsq Yeah, I know that phrase is kinda vague. "_A lot_" usually translates to whenever I'm working with some kind of external event system, such as (jqLite) DOM events. If I'm reading [this answer correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18626099/799327), then that's exactly the correct use-case. It just still feels, well, ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$scope.$evalAsync()` instead.  This will also potentially give you better performance because the action might be performed in the already initiated digest.

Reference: [$scope.$evalAsync() vs. $timeout() In AngularJS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2605-scope-evalasync-vs-timeout-in-angularjs.htm)