# In Angular, is there a way to call code when $routeProvider.otherwise is fired?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I know there is no catchall controller for Angular.  E.g.:

```
 $routeProvider.otherwise({
 controller: 'CatchAllCtrl'
 });
```

However, is there a way to call some code if $routeProvider.otherwise is triggered so I can at least know that otherwise was called and what the route was?

Answer (score 2):

You could redirect to a catchcall route, which could execute your "otherwise" logic, and then manually redirect to an actual view in your app.

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: '/partials/index.html', 
    controller: 'homeController'
  })
  .when('/otherwise', {
    controller:  'otherwiseController'
  })
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/otherwise' });
```

In your otherwiseController, you can inject $location and then set `$location.path("/")` to redirect to wherever you want to go.

You might need to specify a templateUrl for the /otherwise route (I'm not sure).

Comment: Hi CJ, I updated my question to clarify I also need to know what the route was.  If you look at $location.$$path it is set to '/otherwise' which doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to a route change and perform the required action in the callback.

```
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
    var path = $location.path();
     // this shoudl fire for all routes
  }):
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I'm particularly interested in a fresh page when the user pastes in the URL and isn't in an existing controller.  Also, I wouldn't want to paste that code into every controller.  It seems config doesn't accept $rootScope.  Is there a central place where your example can be called?

Comment: put it in a service then

Comment: You just need to have this code executed once. No need to put it into every controller...

Answer (score 0):

Kind of a Angular newbie here, so take everything with salt :)

Can't you simply put the code you want to be executed on "otherwise" inside the "CatchAllCtrl"?

Or maybe, you can update a control variable whenever you reach "otherwise" and use the `$scope.watch` to catch it's change
[How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)