# AngularJS mathematical calculations with ng-model, ng-click buttons, outputting the results in web app

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm starting with AngularJS, learning it bit by bit. For several days now, I am trying to understand how to calculate between ng-models (scopes) in a web-application.

Here is what I am trying to solve as an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/M2b7GNcbgM30phLXT8pU There, if I buy a stack (one click on the 1st button) of papers, then I sell 2 sheets (2 clicks on the 2nd button), the result should show "You have 1.998 stacks"

**HTML**

```
First we buy a stack of papers…
<button input type="button" class="btn" name="StackOfPaper" ng-model="StackOfPaper" ng-click="StackOfPaper = StackOfPaper + 1" ng-init="StackOfPaper=0">Buy a stack of papers<br>(total bought: {{StackOfPaper|number:3}})</button><br><br>

…then we sell individual paper sheets…
<button input type="button" class="btn" name="PaperSheet" ng-model="PaperSheet" ng-click="PaperSheet = PaperSheet + 1" ng-init="PaperSheet=0">Sell a paper sheet<br>(total sold: {{PaperSheet}})</button><br><br>

…get the number of sheets left in the stacks<br> 
You have {{whatsleft|number:3}} stacks
```

**JS**

```
var app = angular.module('paper', []);

$scope.$watch(function() {
    return Math.floor($scope.StackOfPaper*1000 - $scope.PaperSheet);
}, function(SheetsLeft) {
    $scope.SheetsLeft = whatsleft;
});
```

Could you please help me, or suggest a good tutorial for this, I have tried all the combinations other people used, read tons of how-tos, but nothing worked for me. Maybe I am omitting some small things there?

Or is there a better way of doing the said things?
Thank you for the explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an [updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sMcQna?p=preview).

Since you are doing all of your scope stuff in the template right now.  The easiest solution is to do the math inline:

```
You have {{StackOfPaper - (PaperSheet * .001)|number:3}} stacks
```

However, it is probably best (because you can test it easier) to have a controller that allows you to work on your model separate from the view.

[Here is a second plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3YWgkt?p=preview).

With the controller:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.total = 0;
      $scope.stacks = 0;
      $scope.soldSheets = 0;

      $scope.calculateTotal = function() {

        $scope.total = $scope.stacks - ($scope.soldSheets * .001);
      }

      $scope.addStack = function() {

        $scope.stacks = $scope.stacks + 1;
        $scope.calculateTotal();
      }

      $scope.sellSheet = function() {

        $scope.soldSheets = $scope.soldSheets + 1;
        $scope.calculateTotal();
      }
});
```

This cleans up the HTML:

```
You have {{total|number:3}} stacks
```

Comment: Your math is different than what the OP seems to want.  I think it should be:  (StackOfPaper - (PaperSheet * 0.001))

Comment: Your code now matches what *his* code did, but *his* code was inconsistent with his introductory text which implied he wanted 1 stack to = 1000 sheets of paper and have the output displayed in units of stacks.  In any case, I think you answer explains the angularjs best practices of how to accomplish this (whatever the math is supposed to be).

Comment: I'm obviously confused about the requirement! :) But, as you said, I think the OP should be able to figure it out from here.

Comment: @Davin Tryon: Thank you very much for your answer! I have spent several hours now, trying to understand it as best as I could, so that I can replicate the logic next time, myself. Your solution has vastly improved my understanding of the scope function and gave me a solid spot, from wich I can leap forward.

Comment: @ErvWalter: Yes, you are right, I have made a mistake there, what I meant was 0.001 instead of the 1000. Thank you for the input aand correction.

Answer (score 3):

Since Davin's answer should solve your problem, I just want to clarify some things. `$scope.$watch` is useful to watch for scope changes and trigger some action when a certain variable is changed eg:

```js
$scope.someVar = 0

$scope.foo = function(){
    $scope.someVar += 1
}

$scope.$watch('someVar', function(newValue, oldValue){ /* do some magic */ })
```

Business logic should be done by controller functions. Try not to do it in the view.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113029/535025) to understand how things works in Angular.

Comment: thank you! This also helps my understanding of the topic. Great link.