# AngularJS : view is not updated?

Tags: angularjs

I have this simple markup : ([**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/IWedoYiP/4/edit))

```
  <div ng-app data-ng-controller="HelloWorldController">
    <div>
        <label>Message :
            <input ng-model="message">
        </label>
        <h1>{{message}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where  :

```
  function HelloWorldController($scope)
  { var i=0;
    setInterval(function (){i++; 
                            console.log("Hello World "+i);
                            $scope.message="Hello World "+i;},1000);

  }
```

In the console it *does* show me the intervals :

[image]

But in the View - I don't see it  ,and I should see it:

[image]

**Question :**

What am I missing here and why it doesn't update my view ?

Comment: may be this is useful - http://angular-tips.com/blog/2013/08/watch-how-the-apply-runs-a-digest/

Comment: I removed my comment after I reread your post. To better understand what is going on, see this post: http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: here is a working bin. http://jsbin.com/IWedoYiP/9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually enter angular digest cycle to update views. use $scope.$apply in your controller:

```
function HelloWorldController($scope) {
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    i++;
    console.log("Hello World " + i);
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.message = "Hello World " + i;
    });
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: apply is like :"commit the change" ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir close enough, http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

Comment: So why does this sample (http://i.stack.imgur.com/nbWGd.png) dont required apply ?

Comment: Because everything you did with angular's method will automatically trigger digest. `setInterval` is not a angular method, thus its callback need manually trigger angular digest.

Comment: @RoyiNamir You can use `$interval` service to auto trigger digest http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$interval

Answer (score 1):

You should be using Angular's `$timeout` service (I prefer this over manually causing Angular to run a digest cycle by using `$scope.$apply`).  You don't want your Angular code littered with those statements.

So your code should be (Note that you will have to inject the timeout service):

```
function HelloWorldController($scope, $timeout){ 
     var i=0;
     $timeout(function () {
          i++; 
          console.log("Hello World "+i);
          $scope.message="Hello World "+i;
        },1000);
}
```

Comment: So why does this sample (http://i.stack.imgur.com/nbWGd.png) dont required apply ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to $apply your scope. Edit your code as follows

```
  function HelloWorldController($scope)
  { var i=0;
    setInterval(function (){i++; 
                            console.log("Hello World "+i);
                            $scope.message="Hello World "+i;
$scope.$apply();
},1000);

  }
```

Comment: When you using setInterval your code is executed outside of angular. So you need to aware the angular about the changes by $scope.$apply.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply

Answer (score 1):

if you add $scope.$apply(); after you have modified your scope it will update the ui.

Answer (score 1):

A apply is not occuring. To do this without using an apply (and on an interval) 
You can use a promise, coincidentally `$timeout` uses these by default. 
To make your example work you can do this:

```
function HelloWorldController($scope,$timeout){
    var i=0;
    (function doStuff() {
        i++;
        console.log("Hello World "+i);
        $scope.message="Hello World "+i;
        $timeout(doStuff, 1000);
    }());   
}
```

Working JSBin: 
http://jsbin.com/IWedoYiP/9/

By using timeout. The callback is automatically resolved inside a promise. Which causes a digest. Automatically updating the view.

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell your call to setInterval is not being picked up by Angular. You need to call $scope.$apply() as mentioned in this article:

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

which clearly explains the details of what is going.

Also, as mentioned in the article, you should NOT have to use $scope.$apply if you use $timeout instead of setInterval.

Answer (score 1):

Using setInterval angularjs don't know what happens so 
you should do like

```
app.controller('HelloWorldController',function($scope){
               var i=0;
                setInterval(function (){i++; 
                    console.log("Hello World "+i);
                    $scope.$apply(function(){
                            $scope.message="Hello World "+i;
                        }
                    );   
               },1000);

        });
```