# Is there a way to 1-way bind a model to another model in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When my app loads, it sends a request to the back-end to load a coarse grained JSON payload and I store it in `$scope.data`.

Then I want to fetch a property from `$scope.data` and store it in `$scope.netWorkDetails` (code is just an example):

```
$scope.networkDetails = {
  type: $scope.data.network.type;
}
```

Is there a way to bind `$scope.networkDetails` to `$scope.data.network.type`, so that it gets updated whenever `$scope.networkDetails` changes?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I should use `scope.$watch`...

In case someone else stumbles upon this problem:

```
$scope.$watch("myModel.fullName", function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.myOtherModel = {
     fullName: newValue
  };
});
```

Comment: Care to show us how it should be used? You can answer and get upvoted for your own questions.

Comment: There are already many SO post explaining [how (and why) to use $watch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)