# Change a scope value in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Whats the best way to assign a new value through a directive? A two way databinding.

I have a fiddle here where i tried. http://jsfiddle.net/user1572526/grLfD/2/ . But it dosen't work.

My directive:

```
myApp.directive('highlighter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
               scope: {
                    activeInput: '='
                },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function () {
                scope.activeInput = attrs.setInput 
            })
        }
    }
});
```

And my controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
             $scope.active = {
                value : true
            };
}
```

And my view:

```
<h1 highlighter active-input="active.value" set-input="false">Click me to update Value in scope: {{active}}</h1>
```

So what i wanna do is update the scope.active with the given attribute setInput.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using scope.$watch and scope.$apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `element.bind` you leave the realm of Angular, so you need to tell Angular that something had happened. You do that with the `scope.$apply` function:

```
scope.$apply(function(){
  scope.activeInput = attrs.setInput;
});
```

here is an [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xnr3g/).

Comment: :), had the link in the clipboard when your answer appeared!

Comment: @DavinTryon I figured it was a race. Still a very nice gesture from you, to update my answer with an example. But eventually, question will probably be closed as dupe anyway. :)