# when to use scope.$apply in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In line 14 of http://plnkr.co/edit/KuHG70qx64DnBGnQJ9kC?p=preview

We see the usage of `scope.$apply`. In normal case we don't need that, is it because of the scope different we use that? In that case, the param of scope refer to what? The main controller scope?

I'm confused..

Comment: You need to include the minimal example of your question inside the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To know more about $apply and $digest cycle, refer

- [Using scope.$watch and scope.$apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)
- [AngularJS and scope.$apply](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)

AngularJS provides two way binding by digest cycle. Two way binding needs to know when and where the changes made. To achieve this, angularjs has digest cycle which will keep on checking variables for the changes. Somecases, angularjs cannot capture the changes. In those scenerio, we have to tell angularjs about changes by calling `$scope.$apply`.