# Controller's data can grow with time: how does Angular know when that happens in order to refresh UI?

Tags: angularjs

Let's say that when the page is first rendered, the controller has no data to return:

```
var data={};

function dataController($scope) {
    $scope.resultsToDisplay = data;
}
```

but as the user works with the page in a variety of ways, information is being assembled "behind the scenes" and is getting appended to `data`.

How does Angular know when to refresh the UI?  Is Angular invoking `dataController()` periodically? Is there anything special that has to be done to `data` variable to tell Angular to "observe" it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the $watch approach.

```
 function dataController($scope) {    
    $scope.data={};
    $scope.$watch('data', function() {
       $scope.resultsToDisplay = $scope.data;
    });
 }
```

Here is a much detailed explanation about $watch [How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)

Answer (score 0):

Since "data" is not a scope variable. I would make a call to scope.$apply() everytime variable "data" is modified.

It will trigger a digest cycle which will update the UI.