# Angular update binding configuration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I've added a new element to the DOM and set it with ng-model attribute.
Since this element didn't exist when document loaded when angular did his stuff the binding doesn't work.

How can I manually add this element to be handled with angular?

I'm sure it has been asked before but I didn't manage to find the answer...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after creating the element at the controller code i used

```
 $compile(element)($scope)
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you'd have to use `$scope.$apply()`.

There's a fine article on this [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

**EDIT:**

Also, there's another question here on StackOverflow that might help. Maybe you need to use `$scope.$watch()` to listen for events and only then, use `$scope.$apply()`

Check out the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply).

Comment: i've tried $scope.$apply() as is but it doesnt work. i'll review the document for details. thanks.

Comment: The article doesn't speak on what I need. perhaps $scope.$watch() can be used as a workaround. i think what i need is $compile