# Event for any change in scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I wanted to have a Dialog box for asking to save the current changes or not. For that I was searching for an event in AngularJS which triggers on change of any scope variable.

As per my logic I will achieve this by creating event on every control and update a variable to say 'Modified' else will have default value.

---

Is there any other way? Since my logic will need an event on every control.

Comment: Add some more details, some code.. Have you tried form.$dirty ?

Comment: I haven't tried $dirty. Whatever I have shared in question is the same as scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a [form directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form), this is pretty simple. The value of `myForm.$dirty` will be true if any property has changed. You can even check an individual field with `myForm.myField.$dirty`.

If you're not using a form, you should probably consider it for what it sounds like you're trying to accomplish. One of my favorite angular features as it makes validation, etc. a breeze!

Reference: [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `$scope.$watch(...)` [on the Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch), there is a great discussion on how `$watch` works [here on another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply?rq=1)

You should, at the very least, be able to trigger alerts when *specific* scope-elements have changed. If you are using a form, then the `$dirty` approach above is absolutely a brilliant way to go.