# Why AngularJS ng-bind does not update the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-bind

Why this little angular module can't update the view when the `ng-bind` property is changed?

```
<body ng-app="bindExample">

<script>
  angular.module('bindExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      var vm = this;
      vm.name = 'Whirled';
      window.setInterval(function(){ vm.name = 'Jon';}, 5000);
    }]);
</script>

<div ng-controller="ExampleController as vm">
    Hello <span ng-bind="vm.name"></span>!
</div>
</body>
```

I'm expecting that after 5 seconds the output changes `Hello Jon` by it stays at `Hello Whirled`. Why is this? Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `$interval` service its

> Angular's wrapper for window.setInterval here is the [DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

```
$interval(function(){
     vm.name = 'Jon';
}, 1000);
```

don't forget to inject `$interval` as,

```
.controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', $interval, function($scope, $interval) { ....
```

when using `setInterval` its out of the angular scope so u need to use `$interval` here. `$interval` is execute against scope,

---

**OR use `$scope.$apply()`**

```
window.setInterval(function(){
    vm.name = 'Jon';
    $scope.$apply();
}, 5000);
```

> $apply enables to integrate changes with the digest cycle

[this answer would be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)

Comment: Thank you. If I call an AJAX to read the value and then apply it to the model in my resource `success` function, do I need to use `$apply` as well?

Comment: If you use angular's $http service for retrieving data from server, so no need to call $scope.apply();

Comment: NO if you use angular `$http` service as #neilhem mentioned in the last comment, but if you use like jquery ajax you need to use `$apply()` there to tell the angular to there is something out side the scope and need to bind to the scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, to use $interval is a solution. Usually you would change the model on a method attribute of $scope. So angular will take the responsibility of updating the view. If you use a jQuery callback inside a directive you would have to use scope.$apply so that angular knows something happend