# s.$watch not registering clearly changed variable?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, watch

New to Angular and attempting to use it to real-time filter the results of a checkbox and query-string search, and to display those results on a map.  I have the map load pins off the results of a function which is initially called, but is also theoretically triggered by a `$watch` function (in Coffee Script:

```
angular.module("Common").directive 'bucketMap', (... QueryString, PlaceFilterer, $compile, $timeout) ->

  return {

    ...

    link: (s, element) ->

      ...

      s.filterPlaces = (rawPlaces) ->
        s.primaryPlaces = PlaceFilterer.returnFiltered(rawPlaces)

      s.drawMap = (s, elem) ->

        s.$watch 'QueryString.changesInQuery', ->
          console.log "Map Filter: #{QueryString.changesInQuery}"
          # IDEALLY I WOULD THEN RE-EXECUTE THE FILTER SCRIPT
          # E.G. with s.filterPlaces(s.rawPlaces)

        ...
```

I'm testing with the `console.log` how many times `s.$watch 'QueryString.changesInQuery', ->` gets hit (also have a `console.log` in the `QueryString` module which reports every time `QueryString.changesInQuery` is updated.  But my `s.$watch` function is only hit on initial load and never again runs, despite the underlying variable (`QueryString.changesInQuery`) changing demonstrably -- e.g. the contents of my console log as I edit checkboxes on the page looks like this:

```
query_string.js?body=1:62 QueryString: 0
bucket_map.js?body=1:45 Map Filter: 0
query_string.js?body=1:62 QueryString: 1
query_string.js?body=1:62 QueryString: 2
query_string.js?body=1:62 QueryString: 3
query_string.js?body=1:62 QueryString: 4
```

So clearly the variable **is** changing, but is **not** being registered by my $watch function.

I read the very helpful SO post ([How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)) and thought this was a perfect instance of using $watch to track a variable and then rerun my filtering process -- but am guessing I've not applied it correctly in this context.