# Doesn't send the $scope to the html

Tags: ajax, angularjs, spring

I started to work in Angular few days ago, and I have a problem that I don't know how to fix.
My website is calling a controller.js and this controller calls to an ajax function. The ajax function sent back a correct response, but I can't see it in the web. Here is the code:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);
myApp.controller('ResolveProduct', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    productInformation = function($scope) { 
        var something;
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            dataType : "json",
            async : true,
            url : "/ajax/reference/200-B2",
            success : function(data) {
                something = data.david;
                alert(JSON.stringify(something));
                $scope.helper = JSON.stringify(something);      
            },
            complete : function($scope) {
                $scope.helper = JSON.stringify(something);
                alert($scope.helper);
            }
        });
    };
}]);
```

This sent me a correct answer, but when I do this in the HTML I don't see the answer. (Even if the alert has all the info)

```
<div ng-controller="ResolveProduct">
    <input ng-model="info"></input> information is: {{ $scope.helper }}

    <input type="button" id="commitAction" class="slim-button" value="Resolve"  onclick="productInformation('')"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to call `$scope` in the html side, so change `{{$scope.helper}}`  to `{{helper}}`

```
<div ng-controller="ResolveProduct">
                <input ng-model="info"></input> information is: {{ helper }}

                <input type="button" id="commitAction" class="slim-button" value="Resolve"  onclick="productInformation('')"/>
            </div>
```

### Update

You have passed empty values to the `$scope` from the `onclick="productInformation('')"` method. So the  `$scope` values are cleared .

---

Please copy and past my code instead of your code.

**Js code**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myapp',[]);
myApp.controller('ResolveProduct', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.productInformation = function() 
          { 
              var something;
                  $.ajax({
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType : "json",
                  async : true,
                  url : "/ajax/reference/200-B2",
              success : function(data){

                  something = data.david;
                  alert(JSON.stringify(something));
                  $scope.helper = JSON.stringify(something);

              },
              complete : function($scope){
                  $scope.helper = JSON.stringify(something);
                  alert($scope.helper);
              }
          });

          };
}]);
```

**Html Code**

```
<div ng-controller="ResolveProduct">
                    <input ng-model="info"></input> information is: {{ helper }}

                    <input type="button" id="commitAction" class="slim-button" value="Resolve"  **ng-click="productInformation()"**/>
                </div>
```

Also, I have changed `onclick` to `ng-click` in your button and assigned the function with `$scope` in your js side ( see the change  `productInformation` to   `$scope.productInformation`)

Comment: @David_Garcia . I have update my answer, please try this

Comment: Thanks @Ramesh!!! that was very usefull, the only missing thing is what @Cosmin said that you need to do a $scope.$apply()

Answer (score 1):

You should use `{{ helper }}` instead of `{{ $scope.helper }}`.

Also, after `$scope.helper = JSON.stringify(something);` you should add `$scope.$apply()`.

You need to call `$scope.$apply()` because you are assigning a value to `$scope.helper` outside the digest loop (because you are using `$.ajax` from jQuery).

An explanation for the digest loop in angular can be found here: [How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether it works

```
<div ng-controller="ResolveProduct">
    <input ng-model="info"></input> information is: {{helper }}

   <input type="button" id="commitAction" class="slim-button" value="Resolve"  onclick="productInformation('')"/>
        </div>
```

You can't use $scope here
Refer this for help:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2457-accessing-scope-on-the-dom-using-angularjs.htm