# AngularJS ng-repeat data in directive from parent?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to get data from a form element and then insert a  using jQuery .after() to display possible choices. My direct gets the possible matches from the form by getting a attribute called "data" that is loaded by using AngularJS. The issue now, is when I try to ng-repeat with the new inserted  it doesn't list it.

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('autoComplete', [])
    .directive('autoComplete', autoComplete);

function autoComplete($parse)  {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'EA',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: link,
    };

    return directive;

    function link(scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
        var modelGet = $parse(attr['ngModel']);
        var modelSet = modelGet.assign;
        scope.$watch(function() {
            return modelGet(scope);
        }, function() {
            var string = modelGet(scope);
            if (string != undefined && string.length > 6) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.data = attr.data;
                vm.width = elem.outerWidth();
                elem.after('<div><ul class="list-group" style="position: absolute; width: '+vm.width+'px;"><li class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="codes in vm.data track by $index">{{code}}</li></ul></div>');

                console.log(vm.data); //This outputs the data just fine
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Once that  is placed in, the only things that is produced on the screen is {{code}}. I'm assuming I should be trying to compile this somehow in angular?

Comment: Yes for this to work you need to compile, but why do you do this like this in Jquery and not in a regular more angular-y way ?

Comment: Any idea what the best way would be?

Comment: I'd say minimize the JQuery, could you create a fiddle of what you have at the moment ? Would be much easier to work on that.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a `$scope.apply()` after `elem.after(...` to help digest the changes made in the `$scope.watch()`.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113029/2242217

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? If you need to clarify something, use comments

Comment: No clarity was needed, it was rhetorical.  Answer has been updated.