# AngularJS data binding single value to two variables. Second variable not updating in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a textbox who's value is bound to `$scope.stringOne` in my controller. I then have a second variable, `$scope.stringTwo` which is a concatenation of `stringOne` and more text.

However, when I type in the textbox, `stringOne` is successfully updated in the View, but `stringTwo` remains unchanged.

What else is needed to make this work, so that the `stringTwo` value is also updated when `stringOne` is updated?

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="container">       
        <label>Enter Text</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="stringOne"/>
        <h1>{{stringOne}}</h1>
        <h1>{{stringTwo}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope,) {

$scope.stringOne = '';
$scope.stringTwo = $scope.stringOne + ' more texts';

}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $watch

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope',function ($scope,) {

    $scope.stringOne = '';
    $scope.$watch('stringOne', function(new_value){
        $scope.stringTwo = new_value + ' more texts';
    });
}]);
```

Official [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)
Helpful post about [watch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)

---

Why this happens

When you initialize your `$scope.stringOne` it receives empty string, and when you add it in html `ng-model` attribute, it basically watches that variable for changes, but `$scope.stringTwo` you need to watch it yourself

Comment: I'm struggling to understand why `$scope.stringTwo` has fallen outside the scope of being automatically watched, since I though it was bound to the view with `{{stringTwo}}`.

So is ng-model creating a watcher for me, in regards to `stringOne`? And simple binding to a view doesn't necessarily create a watcher?

Comment: View doesn't know about changes of `stringTwo` because it was initialized, with value ` $scope.stringOne + ' more texts'` but it's not changed, only initialized, it doesn't know about changes of `$scope.stringOne`, it just received empty string from it

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them in template, and see changing.
`<h1>{{stringOne + stringTwo}}</h1>`

Demo:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('mainCtrl',function ($scope) {

$scope.stringOne = '';
$scope.stringTwo = 'more texts';

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <div class="container">       
        <label>Enter Text</label>
        <input type="text" ng-model="stringOne"/>
        <h1>{{stringOne}}</h1>
        <h1>{{stringOne + stringTwo}}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: While this could work, I probably should have explained my setup better. The reason that I'm combining in the controller and not in the view, is because `stringTwo` is used as a variable in other functions as well. So if I were to combine them in the view, I would not have a usable variable in the controller.