# Clear ng-model value in controller after ng-click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-click

I need to change the `ng-model` value to empty after `ng-click`

My code:

```
<div class="desc-gestures-comment ind-row">
  <textarea id="txtCommentArea" class="comment-box text-comment-listing" name="comment" placeholder="Your comment" data-ng-model="newCommentTxt">  </textarea>

  <p class="text-center"><span class="btn-common btn-blue btn-large" data-ng-click="saveParentComment(newCommentTxt)">Post Comment</span></p>
</div>
```

Controller function

```
$scope.saveParentComment = function(newCommentTxt){
  alert(newCommentTxt)
  $scope.newCommentTxt = '';
}
```

After the `$scope.saveParentComment`, I need to change the `newCommentTxt` value to empty.

Is it possible ?

Please suggest solution.

Comment: yes. It is possible. You can assign any value to ng-model inside controller.

Comment: what is the problem you are facing.

Comment: yes, it ok, https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope

Comment: you can use $scope.$watch ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/angularjs-using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply

Comment: I tried but the value is not changing.. The ng-model value only i can paas through the parameter otherwise **$scope.newCommentTxt** is undefined

Comment: make sure you are using this html markup inside ng-app='yourApp' and ng-controller='yourController'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You dont have to pass the value inside a function since the scope variable is already there, just need to make the scope variable empty in your function,

```
 $scope.saveParentComment = function () {
        $scope.newCommentTxt = "";
    };
```

Here is the sample [`Application`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/m2myygm2/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!.I am using the same code on my end. I solved the problem.This issue is because of i am using ng-if on my end that will not pass the ng-model value. I changed ng-if to ng-show now its working fine

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set empty string to `$scope.newCommentTxt`, then there is no need to do it inside a function.

You can set empty string inside html code itself.

```
data-ng-click="saveParentComment();newCommentTxt=''";
```

Comment: this is similar and it works: 
ng-click="saveParentComment();newCommentTxt=undefined"

Answer (score -3):

Just make a empty scope variable like **$scope.newCommentTxt = '';** the variable will be empty when the ng-click functions is called the should be like this

Post Comment