# confused about the need for $scope.$apply

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular controller:

```
.controller('DashCtrl', function($scope, Auth) {
    $scope.login = function() {
        Auth.login().then(function(result) {
            $scope.userInfo = result;
        });
    };
});
```

Which is using a service I created:

```
.service('Auth', function($window) {
    var authContext = $window.Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(...);

    this.login = function() {
        return authContext.acquireTokenAsync(...)
            .then(function(authResult) {
                return authResult.userInfo;
            });

    };
});
```

The Auth service is using a Cordova plugin which would be outside of the angular world. I guess I am not clear when you need to use a `$scope.$apply` to update your $scope and when you don't. My incorrect assumption was since I had wrapped the logic into an angular service then I wouldn't need it in this instance, but nothing gets updated unless I wrap the `$scope.userInfo =` statement in a `$timeout` or `$scope.$apply`.

Why is it necessary in this case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS : Using scope.$watch and scope.$apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/angularjs-using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply)

Comment: Does `authContext.acquireTokenAsync(...)` use `$http`?

Comment: @Daniel Nope. It is a cordova plugin so it will be a hook to call native java code for an Android application.

Comment: So it makes sense, angular's `$http` is what triggers the `digest cycle` with `$apply` on an Async callback event. posted an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [angular's wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/When-to-use-$scope.$apply()):

> AngularJS provides wrappers for common native JS async behaviors:
>
> ...
>
> jQuery.ajax() => $http
>
> This is just a traditional async function with a $scope.$apply()
>   called at the end, to tell AngularJS that an asynchronous event just
>   occurred.

So i guess since your `Auth` service does not use angular's `$http`, `$scope.$apply()` isn't called by angular after executing the Async `Auth` function.

> Whenever possible, use AngularJS services instead of native. If you're
>   creating an AngularJS service (such as for sockets) it should have a
>   $scope.$apply() anywhere it fires a callback.

EDIT:

In your case, you should trigger the [digest cycle](https://www.ng-book.com/p/The-Digest-Loop-and-apply/) once the model is updated by wrapping (as you did):

```
Auth.login().then(function(result) {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
      $scope.userInfo = result;
   });
});
```

Or

```
Auth.login().then(function(result) {
    $scope.userInfo = result;
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

Comment: Would the recommendation be to add a $scope.$apply inside of the service then? Instead of having to add $scope.$apply to all of the controllers that are using the service?

Comment: I think since the actual assignment happens in the controller, wrapping the `$scope.userInfo = ` statement as you did (or calling `$scope.$apply()` after it) is the best way. otherwise you might trigger the `digest cycle` before the model is updated.

Answer (score 2):

Angular does not know that `$scope.userInfo` was modified, so the digest cycle needs to be executed via the use of `$scope.$apply` to apply the changes to `$scope`.

Yes, `$timeout` will also trigger the digest cycle. It is simply the Angular version of `setTimeout` that will execute `$scope.$apply` after the wrapped code has been run.

In your case, `$scope.$apply()` would suffice.

NB: `$timeout` also has exception handling and returns a promise.