# When do we need to manually $watch a scope variable in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Like the title says, I wonder when the scope variable can not be auto watched? Is that correct that all the scope variable that not specified in template should be manually watched if I want to monitor their value changing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You do not **need** to `$watch` any variables or scope properties unless you would like to be notified when they are changed.

Angular implicitly places a `$watch` on expressions referenced in templates, i.e. `{{ x + y }}` would place a watch on the result of `$scope.x + $scope.y`. When these watchers fire, Angular knows to update the view.

Comment: Thanks, so my understand is basically correct that if I want to monitor scope variable( which not specify in template) change, I need manually watch them?

Comment: Correct. Even if the variable **is** specified in template, you can't "hook into" Angular's watcher to perform some custom tasks. Any time you need to be notified of changes to a scope expression (regardless of whether it is in the template), you must place a manual watch on it.

Answer (score 0):

**All the binded variables are watched by Angular**, you don't need to say that you want to watch them, **but not all scope variables are watched** by Angular.

Watching a variable means that you are gonna be notified when the value of the variable changes. For example, you could show a pop-up when the total is greater than $10. Then you watch the total variable and you perform the action (showing the pop-up).

You can read this question and learn more about watch and Angular: [How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs)