# console.log for $scope in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller, console.log

Why I'm not able to console output $scope values ? I'm trying to extract user assigned values from the pages and retrieve in controller. Eventually i would like to pass this to service so multiple controllers can access these data.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us" ng-app="myApp">
    <head>
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />    
            <!-- CDN lib files -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>    

            <!-- custom angular script -->
            <script src="js/app.js"></script>  
    </head>
     <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div ng-controller="mainController">
                <h1>Hello world!</h1>
                <label> Please enter something</label>
                <input textarea ng-model="name"></input>
                <h4> This is what you entered : {{ name }} </h4>
                <h4 style=color:red> now filtering: {{ lower() }}</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

APP.JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.name = 'Test ';  
    $scope.lower = function(){
        return $filter('lowercase')($scope.name);
    }

    $scope.name = $scope.lower();

    console.log($scope.name);
    console.log($scope.lower());

}]);
```

Console will output values upon initializing but not after user make changes.

[image]

Comment: On screen model is changing due to two-way data binding where scope is being watched. But in case of console.log(), you need to set watcher manually if you want it to console to model value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to watch the scope variable:

```
$scope.$watch('name', function() {
    console.log($scope.name);
});
```

More information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113029/5787736

Answer (score 3):

Just a more "functional" version. Everyone is right, you are logging the observable, not what was observed. What you want is for `console.log` to be called on each change to `$scope`, not called once (as you have it now).

```
$scope.$watch("name", console.log);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're logging only from the constructor.  If you want to log each time something changes, consider a watch:

```
$scope.$watch("name", function() {
    console.log($scope.name);        
}
```

Comment: @Carlton, beat me by seconds. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect a controller to be rerendered when a scope variable changes? You can use scope watchers or input event listeners to listen for changes.

Here's an example with a watcher:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', ['$scope', '$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.name = 'Test ';  
    $scope.lower = function(){
        return $filter('lowercase')($scope.name);
    }

    $scope.name = $scope.lower();

    console.log($scope.name);
    console.log($scope.lower());
  
    $scope.$watch('name', function() {
        console.log($scope.name);
        console.log($scope.lower());
    });

}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" class="container">
  <div ng-controller="mainController">
    <h1>Hello world!</h1>
    <label>Please enter something</label>
    <input textarea ng-model="name" />
    <h4> This is what you entered : {{ name }} </h4>
    <h4 style=color:red> now filtering: {{ lower() }}</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```