# Watcher in AngularJS does not get fired?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following snippet;

```
vm.products = Product.query();

$scope.$watch("vm.filterType1", function (val) {
            vm.products = $filter('filter')('id', 1);
            console.log('watcher'); 
});
```

html

```
<switch ng-model="vm.filterType1" class="green"></switch>
```

But nothing happends when i change the switch - nothing gets logged in the console?
It runs on load, but not on change.

Comment: please provide a fiddle with your problem

Comment: put vm.products = Product.query(); after $scope.$watch. infact $scope.$watch must be first function in controller

Comment: $scope.$apply();  use this to trigger a watch ...$watch gets triggered only when digest cycle is called ....

Comment: $scope.$apply();  will call the digest cycle to check for the value changed if any

Comment: So i should have a handler for, lets say the switch, which fires $scope.$apply(); on every model change, or?

Comment: your code should work ........do you have your controller above your switch tag  or are you using some custom directive for this ????

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle for your code ???

Comment: you should know that $scope.$watch watches the changed value only during a digest cycle please refer the below link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs?rq=1

Comment: Is the swict tag a custom directive ???

Answer (score 0):

Not excatly an answer, but i used an `ng-change` event instead, and it worked. Thanks for the comments.