# Are $apply, $watch and $digest controller specific or module specific?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

What I wanted to know was when I call say $scope.$apply within a specific controller, are all the scope variables in all other controller with currently active views in the given angular app module also refreshed or only the scope variables in that particular controller?

Comment: maybe could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/rootScope.js#L1055).

```
  $apply: function(expr) {
    try {
      beginPhase('$apply');
      try {
        return this.$eval(expr);
      } finally {
        clearPhase();
      }
    } catch (e) {
      $exceptionHandler(e);
    } finally {
      try {
        $rootScope.$digest();
      } catch (e) {
        $exceptionHandler(e);
        throw e;
      }
    }
  },
```

The `$apply` function triggers a `$digest` on `$rootScope`. This means all the watch functions of the entire app get evaluated.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification