# Monitoring Online and Offline States in an Ionic Application

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to monitor in real time if a user's device is online or offline.
I basically use the info from this site: http://www.joshmorony.com/monitoring-online-and-offline-states-in-an-ionic-application/

I was "upgrading" the code a bit but I still have problems to receive real time network state changes. In my factory is a function called `startWatching()` which works awesome - anytime inside the factory and after I access it the **first** time.

My question: How can I access the changes of the network state inside my controller in real time? I need to show the user some info every time his device is offline.

My controller:

```
  // ### News ###
  var newsCtrl = function ($scope, $http, $ionicLoading, PostService, BookMarkService, ConnectivityMonitor) {
    console.log('newsCtrl');

    var showNews = false;
    ConnectivityMonitor.startWatching().then(function(result) {
      // promise
      console.log('ConnectivityMonitor result: ', result);
      showNews = result;
      $scope.showNews = showNews;

      console.log('showNews: ', showNews);
      if(showNews) {
        displayNews();
      }
    }, function(error) {
      console.error(error);
    });

    function displayNews() {
      // do some stuff
    }
  };
  newsCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$ionicLoading', 'PostService', 'BookMarkService', 'ConnectivityMonitor'];
```

My factory:

```
// ### ConnectivityMonitor ###
var ConnectivityMonitor = function ($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork, $q) {
console.log('ConnectivityMonitor');

var monitorNow = {
  isOnline: isOnline,
  isOffline: isOffline,
  startWatching: startWatching
};
var deferred = $q.defer();

function isOnline() {
  if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()) {
    deferred.resolve($cordovaNetwork.isOnline());
  } else {
    deferred.resolve(navigator.onLine);
  }
  return deferred.promise;
};

 function isOffline() {
  if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()) {
    deferred.resolve(!$cordovaNetwork.isOnline());
  } else {
    deferred.resolve(!navigator.onLine);
  }
  return deferred.promise;
};

function startWatching() {
  if(ionic.Platform.isWebView()){
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:online', function(event, networkState) {
      console.log("went online");
      console.log("event: ", event);
      console.log("networkState: ", networkState);
      deferred.resolve($cordovaNetwork.isOnline());
    });
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState) {
      console.log("went offline");
      console.log("event: ", event);
      console.log("networkState: ", networkState);
      deferred.resolve(!$cordovaNetwork.isOnline());
    });
  }
  else {
    window.addEventListener("online", function(e) {
      console.log("went online");
      console.log("event: ", e);
      deferred.resolve(navigator.onLine);
    }, false);
    window.addEventListener("offline", function(e) {
      console.log("went offline");
      console.log("event: ", e);
      deferred.resolve(!navigator.onLine);
    }, false);
  }
  return deferred.promise;
};

console.log('isOnline: ', monitorNow.isOnline());
console.log('isOffline: ', monitorNow.isOffline());
console.log('startWatching: ', monitorNow.startWatching());

return monitorNow;
};
ConnectivityMonitor.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$cordovaNetwork', '$q'];
```

Comment: Did you manage to get this resolved? I am having the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks quite complicated to me, maybe you want to take a look at a [demo app of mine](https://github.com/swifmaneum/CordovaStarter), which does pretty much the same. It's not an Ionic app, but Angular and TypeScript...

First of all I built a [service](https://github.com/swifmaneum/CordovaStarter/blob/master/CordovaStarter/CordovaStarter/scripts/NetworkStatusService.ts) to get the online state and store it in the variable `deviceIsOnline`.

```
class NetworkStatusService implements INetworkStatusService {
    deviceIsOnline: boolean;

    constructor() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", () => {
            if (navigator.connection.type === Connection.NONE) {
                this.deviceIsOnline = false;
            } else {
                this.deviceIsOnline = true;
            }
        });

        document.addEventListener("offline", () => {
            this.deviceIsOnline = false;
        });
        document.addEventListener("online", () => {
            this.deviceIsOnline = true;
        });
    }
}
```

I'm injecting this service into my [controller](https://github.com/swifmaneum/CordovaStarter/blob/master/CordovaStarter/CordovaStarter/scripts/IndexController.ts) and make use of the `deviceIsOnline` variable.

```
class IndexController {
    static $inject = ["cordovaStarter.NetworkStatusService"];
    constructor(private networkStatusService: INetworkStatusService) {
    }

    showNetworkStatus(): void {
        if (this.networkStatusService.deviceIsOnline) {
            alert("Online");
        } else {
            alert("Offline");
        }
    }
}
```

In your case you might want to [watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) the `deviceIsOnline` variable, so you can execute code everytime the variable changes, instead of reacting on a button click... [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs) might help to understand the watch-pattern, if you don't already know it ;)

---

For the sake of completness, note that I'm hiding my implementation behind following interface:

```
interface INetworkStatusService {
    deviceIsOnline: boolean;
}
```