# Can I trigger ngMessages validation by hand?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-messages

I have an input field with a custom validator and ng-messages to show validation messages.

```
<input type="tel"
       ng-model="ctrl.phoneNumber"
       phone-number
       required />
```

The custom validator is simple:

```
ngModel.$validators.phoneNumber = () => {
    return $iElem.intlTelInput('isValidNumber');
};
```

For some other events I'd like to trigger validation by hand, also simple

```
$iElem.on('countrychange', () => {
    ngModel.$validate();
});
```

Which will trigger my custom validator and also this will validate the number again, the `form.*.$error` object will be updated too, but ngMessages won't reflect, the validation messages won't update somewhy :/

Any idea?

**edit:** when I go for the next input in the line ngMessages kicks in for that input AND for the phone-number input as well and the view gets updated, but it's late, like if it would omit one cycle to update the view

Comment: How is the `countrychange` event triggered?

Comment: @joelkornbluh the jquery intlTelInput plugin will fire it https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input#events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `countrychange` event is not triggered by angular (i.e. outside the digest cycle) you'll need to wrap the validate call inside a `$scope.$apply`.

```
iElem.on('countrychange', () => {
  $scope.$apply(function(){
    ngModel.$validate();
  })
});
```

See [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs) for an explanation

Comment: Thanks, this helped, and fixed my problem ;)