# Update ng-repeat when filter changed dynamically - AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am getting data from a server and then depending on the data I am changing a filter for `ng-repeat`. After I change the filter I am trying to scroll to a new element that will be visible after the `ng-repeat` filter has been updated.

**The problem is that**

I can change the filter dynamically but it takes around 5 seconds for angular to detect the change and update the `ng-repeat`. My scroll code runs immediately after the `ng-repeat` filter has changed, since it hasn't been updated, **I get an error saying**

> the element does not exist.

**My Question is**

How can I make the `ng-repeat` update as soon as the filter is changed and then call my scroll when the `ng-repeat` has finished filtering?

Here is my current code

```
//Set ng-repeat filter
orderTypeFilter = 0;
//Scroll to element that will be visible after ng-repeat finishes updating
var topPos = document.getElementById('cardOrder0').offsetTop;
document.getElementById('main-md-content').scrollTop = topPos - 10;
```

Comment: You have to use [`$scope.$apply`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs), i.e. `$scope.$apply(function(){orderTypeFilter = 0;});`

Comment: Inject `$timeout` to where you're trying to `scrollTop` and put it inside `$timeout(function() { var topPos = document.getElementById.....});`

Comment: I should have added that I am doing this withing a `$mdDialog` controller, so `$scope.apply` does not work. @AlonEitan wouldn't the user have to wait 5 seconds for the `ng-repeat` to change? Is the any way to force the change instead of waiting for it to detect it?

Comment: @GaryJohnson Not when it's inside `$timeout` because it trigger a digest cycle, update the view, and only then attempt to scroll

Comment: @AlonEitan adding the `$timeout` works, but the `ng-repeat` still takes around 5 seconds to update.

Comment: @GaryJohnson In that case you need to show us how you update the array of the `ngRepeat` - Something isn't right there (Maybe you're still using jQuery's `$.ajax`??)