# Changes don't automatically appear on the view (AngularJS update)

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

In my ASP.Net/MVC application, I am using AngularJS to display a list of records from the database. When I update a record, it doesn't get updated in the view (html) until I refresh the page?

The view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="bu in bus">
  <td>{{bu.BU_Name}}</a></td>
  <td>{{bu.BU_Info}}</a></td>
  <th><a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="editItem(bu)">Del</a></th>
</tr>
```

The JS:

```
$scope.editItem= function (bu) {
    $http.post('/CO/DelBU', {dbunt: bu})
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.bus = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
};
```

The MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
    public JsonResult DelBU(BUs dbunt)
    {
        var db = new scaleDBEntities(); 
        var burecord = db.Buses.Find(dbunt.BU_ID);
        db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE dbo.BUs SET BU_Name='just a test'");
        var burecords = db.Buses.ToList();
        return Json(burecords, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

So, when I click on edit, the name doesn't change on the screen unless I refresh the page! How can I fix this?

Thank you

Comment: Have you debugged the line: $scope.bus = response.data; to make sure you're getting the list back?

Comment: Well, I would say yes because the same line is used in my http.get when I first display my data from database.

Comment: But you're not getting all your data using a POST function.... The two calls are separate from each other surely?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: I agree with cullimorer...something more is going on in your actual editItem/POST function that you think. You need to place a debug point and see what response.data is.

Comment: You are right, for some reasons, the response.data did not get the updated values?????

Comment: Not sure if this matters, it's been a while since I've done anything in C# Web API, but why do you need the JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet on a method decorated as an HttpPost?

Answer (score -1):

i think you need to setup a watch for bus - see here for more detail:

[How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs)

Comment: Tom, if possible, would you explain more how to use $watch in my code? Thanks

Comment: Angular automatically creates the $watch by the fact that it is bound using the angular {{}} syntax

Comment: since `<tr ng-repeat="bu in bus">` is not {{}} maybe we need to set a $watch from code?

if you do not need to set a $watch by yourself
`$scope.$digest();` right after `$scope.bus = response.data;` should show the updates.