# Angular List refresh/update issue, while creating new list item, service(getAll) call not happeneing

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, modularity

#### Angular List refresh/update issue, while creating new list item

dashboard-controller.js  -  on dashboard.html

```
.controller('DashboardController',
function ($scope, $state, eventService, storage) {

  eventService.getEventList(storage.getCurrentUser().id).then(function (response) {
    c.eventList = response;
  });
```

event-controller.js  -  on create-event.html

```
.controller('EventController',
function ($scope, $state, eventService, storage) {
this.createEvent = function () {
  eventService.create(event).then(this.onResponseSuccess, this.onResponseError);
};
this.onResponseSuccess = function (payload) {
  $state.go('app.dashboard');
};
```

#### Issue:

First time I can retrieve event list on Dashboard page, but once i created new event and comeback to Dashboard screen, the newly created Event is not updated on the list, When I tried to call **getEventList**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've cleared the storage by using ***deleteAll()*** method and then called the service which is working and getting the latest data list..!

```
   eventService.deleteAll();
   eventService.getEventList(storage.getCur...
```

Answer (score 0):

**try using $watch**

> track your event by $watch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/using-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs) is a link which might help you