# set value from js to element with ng required not set frm.$error.required to false

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a button and ng-style that depends on `frm.mybtn.$error.required` like this:

```
ng-style="frm.mybtn.$error.required?{'border-color':'#a94442'}:''"
```

and I set the value of the button from the javascript,
But angular didn't notice that the required is now false
and `frm.mybtn.$error.required` is still set to true

Comment: Finally, I found the solution in another question,   I addad .change()        and it worked: $('[id="' + id + '"]').prop('value',element[0].files[0].name).change();

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the javascript code inside scope digest as below

```
$scope.$apply(code to set value)
```

Or if you have current scope object then

```
  $scope.$digest(code to set value)
```

For more detail ref
[How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/how-do-i-use-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs)

Comment: if I do this it throw an error:$digest  is allready in progress .                    this is  my code (inside a directive) :                                                    $('[id="' + id + '"]').prop('value', "text");

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, its work for me

```
ng-style="form_user.vEmail.$error.required == true ? {'border-bottom':'1px solid #FF2723'}:''"
```

Comment: but ,do you set the value from the js? the required field is still true!!

Comment: can you plz show your entire code plunker or codepen

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `ng-class` directive, which would be better for code reusability. So, you would end up with a class containing your desired styles, and your HTML would look like this:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="email" name="email" ng-required="true" ng-class="{ 'required': myForm.email.$error.required }"/>
```

Also, if you want to apply the style only after the user has input anything, check the `$dirty` variable:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="email" name="email" ng-required="true" ng-class="{ 'required': myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$error.required }"/>
```

See this [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpvBEa).

Comment: Indeed, I left a typo in the codepen. It's fixed now.