# Updating functions using the ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

What do I need to do to keep the message updated when changing the LastMessage?
Thank you in advance.

```js
   angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MessageController', function($scope) {
     getMessage = function(x){
        return "Hello, " + x + ":)";
      }
     $scope.lastMessage = "StackOverflow";
     $scope.message = getMessage($scope.lastMessage);    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MessageController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="lastMessage" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
        <p ng-bind="lastMessage"></p>
        <p ng-bind="message"></p>
      </div>  
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try watching `lastMessage` variable:

```
$scope.$watch('lastMessage ', function() {
    $scope.message = "Hello, " + $scope.lastMessage + ":)";;
});
```

For more information on `watch` and `apply` look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/how-do-i-use-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs).

```js
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MessageController', function($scope) {
     $scope.lastMessage = "StackOverflow";
     $scope.message=$scope.lastMessage;
     $scope.aa="";
     $scope.bb="";
     $scope.$watch('lastMessage',function(){
        $scope.message= "Hello, " + $scope.lastMessage + ":)";
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

 <body ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MessageController">
        <input type="text" ng-model="lastMessage" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
        <p ng-bind="lastMessage"></p>
        <p ng-bind="message"></p>
      </div>
      <p>
        <p ng-bind="aa"></p>
        <p ng-bind="bb"></p>
      </p>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
On this example it worked, I'll try to transfer it to the set of functions that call the variable from $scope in my project.
Thank you all :)

Comment: Glad I'm of some help. There is a caution that using too many `$watch` slows down the app. Also, try moving to `Angular 2`.

Comment: To avoid slowing the app with `$watch`, consider using the [ng-change directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)  on input elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could call getMessage function on ng-change of last message :

```
 angular.module('myApp',[]).controller('MessageController', function($scope) {
 $scope.getMessage = function(x){
     $scope.message = "Hello, " + x + ":)";
  }
 $scope.lastMessage = "StackOverflow";    
});


<body ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="MessageController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastMessage" ng-change="getMessage(lastMessage)" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
    <p ng-bind="lastMessage"></p>
    <p ng-bind="message"></p>
  </div>  
</body>
```

Comment: I tried so, but it did not help.
Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code as shown as below,

Template:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="lastMessage" ng-change="getMessage(lastMessage)" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
<p ng-bind="lastMessage"></p>
<p ng-bind="message"></p>
```

Controller Code:

```
$scope.getMessage = function(x){
  $scope.lastMessage = x;
  $scope.message = "Hello, " + x + ":)";
}
$scope.getMessage('StackOverflow');
```

Comment: I tried so, but it did not help.
Thank you for the answer!

Comment: Here is the plnkr link which works anyway! http://plnkr.co/edit/W9VspRk3fREKJvxjuRcM?p=preview

Comment: Hmm. It's strange. Excuse me.
And thank you very much. I'll try again.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
  <div ng-controller="MessageController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="lastMessage" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
    <p ng-bind="lastMessage"></p>
    <p ng-bind="getMessage(lastMessage)"></p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any specific reason to use ng-bind or functions? Because for something like this you can just do this

```
  <input type="text" ng-model="lastMessage" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
  <p>{{lastMessage}}</p>
  <p ng-if="lastMessage.length"> Hello {{lastMessage}} :)</p>
```

ng-if is in case if you only want to show the message when user has typed something.