# Why this angular scope doesn't show in view only if it is after a HTTP request?

Tags: angularjs, datatable, http-headers, bootstrap-modal

I have remarked a strange behavior in my code , I made a button where the action is to set a scope and show a bootstrap modal with the value of this scope
Normally the code should look like this

But that don't work i only get a empty value in the model

```
var table = $('#data').DataTable();
$('#data tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control,.addsta,.mjump,.mcon,.delwf', function () {    
    if (this.className == "btn btn-danger delwf") {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);
            $scope.sworcode = row.data().worcode;
            $scope.slancode = row.data().lancode;
            console.log(row.data().worcode);
            $('#modal-del').modal('show');
            };
}
```

But if i add a HTTP request like this  the value shows up in the modal

```
var table = $('#data').DataTable();
 $('#data tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control,.addsta,.mjump,.mcon,.delwf', function () {   
        if (this.className == "btn btn-danger delwf") {

            var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
            var row = table.row(tr);

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: localhost + "/test"
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {}, function errorCallback(response) {});
            $scope.sworcode = row.data().worcode;
            $scope.slancode = row.data().lancode;
            console.log(row.data().worcode);
            $('#modal-del').modal('show');

        };
 }
```

Can anyone explain this please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why your code works when you add an http request in your code is that it will triger a $digest cycle which will update the value of your scope variables. Without http also, you can trigger the digest loop by using `$scope.$apply()`

```
var table = $('#data').DataTable();
$('#data tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control,.addsta,.mjump,.mcon,.delwf', function () {    
    if (this.className == "btn btn-danger delwf") {
    var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    var row = table.row(tr);
            $scope.sworcode = row.data().worcode;
            $scope.slancode = row.data().lancode;
            console.log(row.data().worcode);
            $scope.$apply();
            $('#modal-del').modal('show');
            };
}
```

For more Info [How do I use $scope.$watch and $scope.$apply in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112584/how-do-i-use-scope-watch-and-scope-apply-in-angularjs)