# Reloading angular table does not work when the data is loaded in response to an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, multithreading, html-table

I need to populate an angular table when new data from a websocket is received in another frame by there calling parent.postMessage("printComments", "*"):

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
var printOperation;

function GetFromLocalStorage(key) {
    var items = localStorage.getItem(key);
    console.log(items);
    if (items === null) {
        console.log("item null");
        return null;
    } else {
        if (typeof items != "string") {
            items = JSON.stringify(items);
        }
        return items;
    }
}

app.controller('MyCtrl',
    function ($scope) {
        $scope.printComments = function () {
            //$scope.obj=GetFromLocalStorage("AllComments");
            $scope.obj = [{
                "nome": "first",
                "status": 1,
                "testo": "Rottura rullo 1!!!"
            }, {
                "nome": "second",
                "status": 0,
                "testo": "Rottura rullo fsdfsf!!!"
            }];
            console.log("ricevo evento e ricarico tabella");
            console.log($scope.obj);
        };

        console.log("assegno print operation");
        printOperation = $scope.printComments;
        printOperation();
    }
);
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
    console.log("ricevo messaggio");
    printOperation();
}, false);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myapp">
<table ng-table="commentsTable">
  <tr ng-repeat="item in obj track by $index">
    <td class="plantCell">{{item.nome}}: </td>
    <td class="statusCell">{{item.status}}</td>
    <td class="statusCell">{{item.testo}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

If I call printOperation *inside* the scope function, the table is correctly updated, if on the reverse I call it when *I receive the event*, the table is not updated. If it were a Swift or Java program I would think I am on a background thread, is there such a concept in Javascript and how do I come to the main thread?

Comment: I think you have to use a callback since the printOperation() outside the angular is undefined while it is getting executed. So somehow you have to wait for angulars execution to get over .

Comment: Nope, the console message inside the printOperation function is actually printed, so it is not only loaded but also executed. That is quite natural as the scope function is executed as soon as the table is loaded while the event arrives much later when the event is sent.

Comment: It is executed since you placed printOperation(); inside the scope of angular. Try placing it outside then you will understand what I was saying.

Comment: Unfortunately that function sets the array used by the angular table. So it must sit inside the scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to update the data outside of AngulraJS scope (in event listener) and that is why the view doesn't show the updated values. You need to wrap your function call with [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) or ['$applyAsync'](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$applyAsync) to start the digestion cycle explicitly. See a working example:

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

app.controller('MyCtrl',
    function ($scope) {
        //initial data
        $scope.obj = [{
                "nome": "first",
                "status": 1,
                "testo": "Rottura rullo 1!!!"
            }];
            
        //this changes data
        $scope.printComments = function () {
            //$scope.obj=GetFromLocalStorage("AllComments");
            $scope.obj = [{
                "nome": "first",
                "status": 1,
                "testo": "Rottura rullo 1!!!"
            }, {
                "nome": "second",
                "status": 0,
                "testo": "Rottura rullo fsdfsf!!!"
            }];
            console.log("ricevo evento e ricarico tabella");
            console.log($scope.obj);
        };
        
        var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
        var eventer = window[eventMethod];
        var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
        eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
            console.log("ricevo messaggio");
            //kick in $digest
            $scope.$apply($scope.printComments);
        }, false); 
        
        //emulate message in 3 secs
        setTimeout(function(){ window.dispatchEvent( new Event(messageEvent) ); }, 3000);
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myapp">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in obj track by $index">
      <td class="plantCell">{{item.nome}}: </td>
      <td class="statusCell">{{item.status}}</td>
      <td class="statusCell">{{item.testo}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci what AngularJS version are you using?

Comment: I am getting Uncaught TypeError: $scope.$applyAsync and just a row is printed of two. I also have, for that matter, Uncaught TypeError: $(...).resizable is another part of the code.

Comment: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js
are there other ones?

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci, yeah - 1.6.5 is the latest one. `$applyAsync` was introduced in 1.3, so if you are using 1.2, you should try using `$apply` instead of it. Working example updated.

Comment: I tried to load:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js and now I am getting no error but a very long list of rows with just :

Comment: Even with that version I am shortly getting the first correct row and then a very long list of rows with just :

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci how you object `obj` looks like? There shouldn't be any problems if it is the same as in my working fiddle.

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci Isn't there an issue with your `GetFromLocalStorage` function? I think you should use [`parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) (`return JSON.parse(items);`) to construct the value back from the string that was stored in `localStorage`.

Comment: Right: the issue was that one. I got that code from some strange source. As a matter of fact always parsing does the job. Thanks

Comment: You will have an empty table with ":" if repeater will iterate over a string. GetFromLocalStorage("AllComments") returns not an object but string. You have to use [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get the object value from a json string.

Comment: @FabrizioBartolomucci Don't forget to accept the answers if they were helpful :) Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone. This is the working solution collecting all the kind suggestions:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.5/angular.min.js">
</script>
</head>

<body>
<html>
        <div ng-controller="MyCtrl" ng-app="myapp">
        <table ng-table="commentsTable">
            <tr ng-repeat="item in obj track by $index">
                <td class="plantCell">{{item.nome}}: </td>
            <td class="statusCell">{{item.status}}</td>
            <td class="statusCell">{{item.testo}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <script language="javascript">
            var app=angular.module('myapp', []);
            var printOperation;
            function GetFromLocalStorage(key) {
                var items=localStorage.getItem(key);
                console.log(items);
                if (items===null){
                    console.log("item null");
                    return null;
                } else {
                    items = JSON.parse(items);
                    return items;
                }
            }
            var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

            app.controller('MyCtrl',
                    function ($scope) {
                    $scope.printComments = function () {
                            $scope.obj=GetFromLocalStorage("AllComments");
                    console.log("ricevo evento e ricarico tabella");
                    console.log($scope.obj);
                    };
                    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
                    var eventer = window[eventMethod];
                    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
                    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
                            console.log("ricevo messaggio");
                            $scope.$applyAsync($scope.printComments);
                    }, false);  
                }
        );      
        </script>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you accept my answer? Since it resolves the original issue, but the other issues were casued by `GetFromLocalStorage` method which was even commented out in the question's body and is not even related to the question itself.