# oboejs : Nothing happens after JSON response

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, oboe.js

JS:

```
function OrderFormController($scope, $http) {

$scope.sampleJSON = [];
$scope.sampleJSONDuplicates = [];
oboe('/getPMDResultsByDateAndSeverity')
   .done(function(data) {
    $scope.sampleJSON.push(data.pmdStructureWrapper);
    $scope.sampleJSONDuplicates.push(data.pmdDuplicates);
   })
   .fail(function() {

      console.log('error');
   });

}
```

html:

```
<body ng-app ng-controller="OrderFormController">

<div class="splash" ng-cloak="">
    <h2>Please wait, Loading Review Result</h2>
</div>


<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12" ng-cloak="">
    <div class="panel with-nav-tabs panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#tab1default" data-toggle="tab">Classes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab1default">
                    <ul class="col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                        <li ng-click="showErrorDetails(key)" class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 eachClassCell"
                            ng-repeat='(key,value) in sampleJSON'>
                            <div ng-if="key.indexOf('.cls') > -1">
                                <div title="{{key}}" class="classNameLabel">{{key}}</div>
                                <div title="Error count" class="errorContainer">
                                    <span class="errorCount">{{value.pmdStructures.length}}</span>
                                    <span class="errorMeter"
                                          ng-repeat="eachClass in value.pmdStructures | limitTo: 10"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<form>


</form>
<footer>
    <p>Salesforce Free Code Review, Copyright &copy; 2017</p>
    <p>Contact Us : <a href="mailto:****">Mail Us</a>
    </p>
</footer>
<script type="application/javascript">

    $(function() {
        $('.panel-body li').each(function() {
            if($.trim($(this).text()) === "") {
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });


</script>
</body>
```

the page does not render anything.
Is there something I am missing? I know the page renders before the result, but how do I re-render it?
I have to keep it async because when I host my app in heroku the call gets timed out(30000ms),if I use async false from ajax:

```
var jsonData = $.ajax({
        url: "/getPMDResultsByDateAndSeverity",
        dataType: "json",
        crossDomain: true,
        async: false
    }).responseText;
```

Also it keeps running out of heap memory as when I use async false. I have modified the server side to perform at optimal level.
When using async false : c.****.algo.MetadataLoginUtil   : Total Time Taken 26825

After using async true : which I thing oboe.js internally does:

c.****.algo.MetadataLoginUtil   : Total Time Taken 6321

The above is the time taken is for getting response from server side.

Comment: Have you tried calling [`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) at the end of the `done()` method? The async call in oboe is outside of angular, so $apply tells angular to refresh the UI

Comment: Just did, nothing happened.

Comment: Ok, just changed my script to this :

function OrderFormController($scope, $http) {


    oboe('/getPMDResultsByDateAndSeverity')
       .done(function(data) {
        $scope.sampleJSON = data.pmdStructureWrapper;
        $scope.sampleJSONDuplicates = data.pmdDuplicates;
        $scope.$apply();
       })
       .fail(function() {

          console.log('error');
       });

}

Comment: And this worked with apply. Can you please post that as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call [`$scope.$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) at the end of `done()`.

Because the call is async and oboe does not hook into angular's scope framework, angular will not know that the page needs to be re-rendered after you have received the ajax response.

`$scope.$apply()` tells Angular that the scope has changed and to therefore refresh the page display. [This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15113029/1901857) explains this in more detail.

Comment: There is a issue here but, When i apply all the files, regardless of extension type is coming in the tab, as I have written .cls index of >1, its not respecting the if condition and is rendering a box, with no name on it. [link](https://i.imgur.com/JbZZ83e.png); The left side which is blank is actually a .tigger file